# Draw a contour map of the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$, showing several contour lines.

Tags: calculus

For the contour map, we consider $z$ as a constant $k\Rightarrow z=k$, like this:
\begin{align*}
     k = z & = f(x,y)\\
           & = \sqrt{y^2-x^2}\\
     k^2   & = y^2-x^2.
\end{align*}
Since $k=\sqrt{y^2-x^2}\Rightarrow k\geq0$, so we have that if $k=0$, then $y^2 = x^2 \Rightarrow y = -x$ o $y = x$ (which are two lines that pass through the origin, where one is the identity). On the other hand, for $k>0$, we have:
\begin{align*}
     \frac{y^2}{k^2} - \frac{x^2}{k^2} = 1.
\end{align*}
That they are vertical hyperbolas centered on the origin, that the larger $k$ is, the further they move away from the origin of the plane, so the contour lines would look as shown below:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.